# import package external style css to polymer 3 application

Tags: polymer-3.x

I am using selecttreejs npm module and I am trying to import its css style in my polymer3 application, it seems like its not loading completly.
It looks like this, overlapping with background text. How can I import the external css to polymer 3 app.
[image]

> ```
> import { Treeselect } from 'treeselectjs';
> import treeselect from "treeselectjs/dist/treeselect-js.css";
> let myCSSLiteral = htmlLiteral(treeselect); 
> class WorkspaceSelector
> extends PolymerElement {
>   static get template() {
>     return html `
>         <style>
>           ${myCSSLiteral}
>           
>             #workspace-select {
>                 width: 100%;
>             }
>             .sciome-select {
>                 font: 400 16px "acumin-variable-concept";
>                 padding: 5px;
>             }
>             
>         </style>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use the standard `link` tag in your html code.

```
return html`
    <style>
      #workspace-select {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .sciome-select {
        font: 400 16px "acumin-variable-concept";
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>

    <link href="treeselectjs/dist/treeselect-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />;
`;
```